# Аргументы в input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно передать `input` множество аргументов

```
a = input("enter>")
...
...
enter>set name kolya
enter>set age 18
```

И на выводе что типа того, ну что бы понять

```
You name kolya and your age 18
```

как это можно осуществить ?

Answer (score 3):

Функция `input()` принимает только один параметр - строку - и возвращает тоже строку.
Самой простой подход применить её дважды:

```
name, age = input("enter name > "), input("enter age  > ")

print(f"You name is {name} and you are {age} year old")              # Python 3.6+
```

Ввод и вывод:

> ```
> enter name > John
> enter age  > 17
> You name is John and you are 17 year old.
> ```

---

Первую команду возможно писать тоже как *абстракцию списка:*

```
name, age = [input(f"enter {x} > ") for x in ("name", "age")]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print("You name {} and your age {}"
        "".format(input("You name: "), input("your age: ")))
```